# Magento get product id's in array

Tags: javascript, magento

good day.  I'm trying to gather all product id's in my cart within Magento and display them in javascript separated with a semicolon.  I'm very close except I cant seem to get all of the id's to appear.  So far I can only get one product ID. The "itemid" is where I would like these ID's displayed.  Please help thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar= {
    "pagetype": "CART",
    <?php $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) ?>
    "itemid" : "<?php echo $item->getId();  ?>"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to print an array of ID's. The current cenario is producing: `"{id}{id-0}{id-1}{id-2}{id-3}"`

Use to store the ID's in an array to print out a JSON:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar= {
    "pagetype": "CART",
    <?php $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item): 
        array_push($ids, $item->getId()); 
    endforeach; ?>
    "itemid" : <?php echo json_encode($ids);  ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is this possible from external Javascript? I am writing Javascript widget which needs product SKU for furthur processing. I have successfully added external javascript widget url. But stuck at this now. :(

Comment: In this case, we're outputing Magento queries in JSON object, and then processing. You can't query directly the database with client-side javascript, only if you had some middleware contacting the database.